# Arrow filter() with string expressions doesn't work with Shiny. Is there a workaround?

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

In contrast to this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024214/filter-expression-not-supported-for-arrow-datasets), filtering with string expressions does work with Arrow data sets now, but they don't work in the reactive Shiny environment.  **Is there a workaround?** Here is the arrow-ified Shiny demo app.  I've added a textInput() widget and tried to filter on the contents of that.  In the code below, the assignment to `subset` is where the action is.  The Arrow version works outside the Shiny context and it works inside Shiny with a string literal instead of an expression.

```
library(shiny)
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

faithful <- faithful |> 
  mutate(size = if_else(eruptions > 4,"Big One","Little One"))
  
faithful_arrow <- faithful |> 
  as_arrow_table()
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("size","Size",value = "Big"),
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
       subset <- faithful_arrow |> 
         # this breaks inside the Shiny app but works outside it
         filter(str_detect(size,str_to_title(input$size))) |> 
         collect()
       
       # arrow filter works with string literal
       # subset <- faithful_arrow |> 
       #   filter(str_detect(size,str_to_title("Big"))) |> 
       #  collect()
       
         # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- subset[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        
        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape `input` with `!!` to tell `filter()` it's a value from the environment, not from the data:

```r
    subset <- faithful_arrow |> 
      filter(str_detect(size, str_to_title(!!input$size))) |> 
      collect()
```

[image: image of shiny app]

Comment: It works! Thanks. I never would have figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

We need to transform `faithfull_arrow` to `data.frame` class. Because `faithful_arrow` is "Table" "ArrowTabular" "ArrowObject"  "R6":

like here with `as.data.frame`

```
 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    subset <- faithful_arrow |> 
      as.data.frame() |>
      # this breaks inside the Shiny app but works outside it
      filter(str_detect(size,str_to_title(input$size))) |> 
      collect()
```

[image]

Comment: I think the point of using a lazy arrow table to start with is to _not_ pre-collect into a `data.frame`. I do this regularly with larger-than-RAM parquet-stored data.

Comment: as r2evans says, the goal is to collect AFTER the filter step. In the toy example above it doesn't matter but with my 1.5 million row data set, collecting after a working filter operation is about 37 times faster than collecting before filter().